# Custom Marlin update for Ender 3 Pro results in Z minimum endstop for autohome and Z move in negative direction

Tags: marlin, bltouch, creality

Good  day, I bought an z axis extension kit for my ender 3 pro and therefore  needed  to update marlin by myself. I am using the sd card for firmware   flashing. OctoPrint is connected via usb. The BLTouch is v3.1, it is   connected via the 5 pin cable in the slot directly near the LCD slot in   the Motherboard. The Motherboard is 422.

The  problem describes as follows. My printer is not able to move down  on  the z axis. I can move it by z axis moving up but after leaving the   menu or directly reducing the z axis height it wont move down. It also shows in the main menu always z=0 for its position. The Autohome function correctly autohomes x and y axis until it tries to use the bltouch to move down. In this progress the BLTouch stows and deploys the little stick several times until it just stops with autohome shown on   the display or M112 Error.
Also I  am glad if someone might also have other suggestions for  better  configuration settings in those files if someone just sees them.

I can provide configuration.h configuration_adv.h and pins_creality_v4
Thank you for time and best regards.

configuration.h: https://pastebin.com/iA7kNGyZ

configuration_adv.h https://pastebin.com/j9JyfBp9

pins_Creality_V4.h: https://pastebin.com/0f0KPMf4

Problem solved. I was dumb and have over seen the  Z_MIN_PROBE_ENDSTOP  option. This fixed it for me